# How to add worksheet tab name in excel in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have multiple tab in my report and generate multiple  worksheet tab name in excel.

How to add worksheet tab name in excel in SSRS Report?

Answer (score -2):

Select Group properties :
[image]

Under group enter pagename :
[image]